# What topology are we using in solving this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

Here is the problem link (where the title is exactly what we want to prove)

[$L^2$ is meager in $L^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159432/l2-is-meager-in-l1)

My question is:

What topology are we using in solving this problem? could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topology used is the one induced by the $1$-norm i.e. $\Vert f \Vert_1 := \int_{[0,1]} \vert f(x) \vert dx$.

This is well defined since $[0,1]$ has finite Lebesgue measure and thus $L^2([0,1]) \subseteq L^1([0,1])$.

That means, that the topology is generated by the family $\{B_{r}(f): r > 0, f \in L^1([0,1])\}$, where

$$B_{r}(f) := \{g \in L^1([0,1]) : \Vert f-g\Vert_1 < r\} ~~.$$

Hence a set $U \subseteq L^1([0,1])$ is open if and only if $U = \cup_{i \in I} B_{r_i}(f_i)$ where $I$ is some index set.

Comment: and what is it explicitly?

Comment: what are the form of the open sets?

Comment: I have edited and added what that means explicitely.

Comment: why $f$ should belong to $L^1$ and not $L^2$?

Comment: You consider the set $L^2$ with the subspace topology as it is a subspace of $L^1$. The open sets of $L^2$ then have the form $U \cap L^2$ for any $U$ open in $L^1$.

Comment: One more question please: why this set that is defined in a link contained in the above link : For $n \in \mathbb N$ set $B_n = \{f \in L^2[0,1]\mid \|f\|_2 \le n \}$ has $\leq n$ and not <n only?

Comment: And why we are taking in the set I mentioned in my last comment $f \in L^2$ and not $L^1$?

Comment: What we want to show is that $L^2$ is meager i.e. that it is the union of nowhere dense sets. So if we can show that $L^2 \subseteq \cup \{f \in L^1: \Vert f \Vert_1 \leq n \}$, or that $L^2 \subseteq \cup \{f \in L^2: \Vert f \Vert_1 \leq n \}$,  or that $L^2 \subseteq \cup \{f \in L^2: \Vert f \Vert_1< n \}$ or $L^2 \subseteq \cup \{f \in L^2: \int \vert f\vert^2 dx < n \}$. Any of those will suffice.

Comment: ohh why any of those sets are the same?

Comment: why the last set contains the square root of $\|.\|_{2}$?

Comment: I will post now a new question about my last 2 comments I hope you can answer it for me …. I will provide you with the link here.

Comment: Also, if you have time could you look at this question for me please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3585432/why-we-take-u-f-in-l2a-b-f-l2a-b-leq-1 (I am still typing the other question)

Comment: Here is the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3586693/a-question-about-the-sets-used-in-the-proof-of-l2-is-meager-in-l1