# Some intuition about embedding of $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis

Followings are from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings).

1. Why is it that:

> Colloquially, if $1 ≤ p < q ≤ ∞$,
>
> - $L^p(S, μ)$ contains functions that are more **locally singular**,
> - while elements of $L^q(S, μ)$ can be more **spread out**?

I was also wondering what "locally singular" and "spread out" mean
mathematically?

Why is it that:

> Consider the Lebesgue measure on the half line $(0, ∞)$.
>
> - A continuous function in $L^1$ might **blow up near 0** but
>     must **decay sufficiently fast toward infinity**.
> - On the other hand,
>     continuous functions in $L^∞$ need not **decay** at all but no
>     **blow-up** is allowed?

I was also wondering what "blow up (near 0)" and "decay sufficiently
fast  (toward infinity)" mean mathematically?

Although it is stated in the following, I don't understand how this
"precise technical result" related to the above two quotes?

> The precise technical result is the following:
>
> - Let $0 ≤ p < q ≤ ∞$. $L^q(S, μ)$ is contained in $L^p(S, μ)$ iff $S$ does not contain sets of arbitrarily large measure, and
> - Let $0 ≤ p < q ≤ ∞$. $L^p(S, μ)$ is contained in $L^q(S, μ)$ iff $S$ does not contain sets of arbitrarily small non-zero measure.
>   Thanks and regards!

Comment: I believe this approach is far too abstract. As I suggested in a previous question of yours: do you have some toy examples of functions which belong to $L^1[0,1]$, but not $L^2[0,1]$ or $L^2[0,1]$ but not $L^\infty[0,1]$? Do you have some examples of sequences in $\ell^2$, but not in $\ell^1$ or $\ell^\infty$, but not $\ell^2$? If not, find them! If so, try to understand their features and how they meet the descriptions in your post. I would strongly recommend to answer these explicit questions on the simplest of measure spaces, i.e., $[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{N}$, first.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks! http://math.stackexchange.com/a/18399/1281

Answer (score 4):

I guess it suffices to answer the first question. One observation is

> If $|x|>1$, then $|x|^p<|x|^q$. If $|x|<1$, then $|x|^p>|x|^q$.

If $f$ is integrable, then $|f|$ have to decay at infinity (you can take this literally as on $(0,\infty)$, but I think in many other cases this can also be understood). So $|f(x)|<1$ for large $x$. But $|f|^p>|f|^q$ there, so "$f$ is $q$-integrable" puts a weaker restriction on $|f|$ for large $x$ than "$f$ is $p$-integrable".

That is why $\mathcal{L}^q$ functions can be more spread-out than $\mathcal{L}^p$ functions.

Turn this argument around, you see $\mathcal{L}^p$ functions can have more local *blow ups* than $\mathcal{L}^q$ functions.

Comment: Thanks, +1! (1) Does "singular" mean the same as "blow-up"? (2) "Turn this argument around, you see $L^p$ functions can have more local blow ups than $L^q$ functions." Is it because that $L^q$ functions may be less bounded than $L^p$ functions at infinity, to even out their integrals over the domain, $L^q$ functions may have less spikes than $L^p$ functions locally?

Comment: (3) I think in your reply, $p, q \in (0, \infty]$ not just $\in [1, \infty]$?

Comment: (4) in Part 3, how is the blow-up and spread out of $f$ at infinity and locally related to "S does not contain sets of arbitrarily large measure" and "S does not contain sets of arbitrarily small non-zero measure"?