# Intuition for a function that belongs to a $L^p$ space

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

Does a function $f(x):[0,\infty)\rightarrow R$ with $f\in L^p$ for $p<\infty$ have to die down to $0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$? I some how feel that the $L^p$ norm exist only when the function dies down to $0$ and the rate at which it dies down to $0$ depends on $p$. Is this right?

Comment: This is wrong the way you put it: standard counterexamples are "spiky" functions, which do not decay but belong to whatever $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ space you like (with $1\le p < \infty$). Nevertheless, that's a correct idea: somewhat more precisely, I would say that belonging to some $L^p$ space imposes an integral condition of decay at infinity. The bigger the exponent the stricter the condition.

Comment: "spiky" in the sense that f= 1 for integers and 0 every other real number. This function exists in Lp space but does not decay. Is this right?

Comment: for example a triangle at each integer of height $n$, width $1/n^3$ , doesnt "decay" in the sup norm, but the integral is small outside of large enough bounded sets.

Comment: This is a great question, its a shame more people didn't answer. Thanks Giuseppe and yoyo. I also found [this related question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266437/some-intuition-about-embedding-of-lp-spaces)

Answer (score 2):

If by “die down,” you mean “converge to $0$”, then the answer is no. Consider the following function:
\begin{align*}
f(x)\equiv
\begin{cases}
0&\text{if $x\in[0,1)$,}\\
1&\text{if $x\in[1,1+1/1^2)$,}\\
1&\text{if $x\in[2,2+1/2^2)$,}\\
0&\text{if $x\in[2+1/2^2,3)$,}\\
1&\text{if $x\in[3,3+1/3^2)$,}\\
0&\text{if $x\in[3+1/3^2,4)$,}\\
\vdots\\
1&\text{if $x\in[n,n+1/n^2)$,}\\
0&\text{if $x\in[n+1/n^2,n+1)$,}\\
\vdots
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
This function doesn't converge to zero as $x\to\infty$ (nor is it equal almost everywhere to a function that does), yet, for any $p\in[1,\infty)$:
\begin{align*}
\|f\|_p=\left(\int|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm dx\right)^{1/p}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{1/p}=\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right)^{1/p}<\infty.
\end{align*}