# Gagliardo–Nirenberg interpolation for $p=N=1$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces

In "*A First Course in Sobolev Spaces*" by Leoni, the proof for Theorem 12.83 when $p=N=1$ is left as an exercise. However, I have no idea how to prove it; can anyone provide some guidance to the proof for this part of the theorem?

The theorem goes as follows (with $p=N=1)$:

> Let $q\in[1,\infty]$, $\theta\in[0,1]$ and $r=\frac{q}{\theta}$.
>
> Then there exists a constant $c > 0$ (depending only on $q$ and $\theta$) such that
> $$
> ||u||_{L^r(\mathbb{R})} \le c\, ||u||_{L^q(\mathbb{R})}^\theta ||\nabla u||_{L^1(\mathbb{R})}^{1-\theta}
> $$
> for every $u\in L^q(\mathbb{R})\cap\dot{W}^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose ${\|\nabla u\|}_{L^1(\mathbb R)} = \int|u'(x)| \, dx = L$.  Since $u \in L^q(\mathbb R)$, there must be a sequence $x_n \to -\infty$ such that $u(x_n) \to 0$.  Therefore, $u(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{-x_n}^x u'(y) \, dy$.  It follows that $|u(x)| \le L$.  Hence
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} |u(x)|^r \, dx \le L^{r-q} \int_{\mathbb R} |u(x)|^q \, dx ,$$
and taking $r$th roots, the result follows.

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer. Just wanted to ask, why must there exist a sequence $x_n\to-\infty$ with $u(x_n)\to0$? I read in [this article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606094/intuition-for-a-function-that-belongs-to-a-lp-space) that tails of $L^q$ functions might not necessarily decay to $0$.

Comment: If there doesn't exist such a sequence, then there exists some $A>0$, $B\in\mathbb R$ such that $|u(x)|>A$ for $x<B$.  But then the $L^q$ norm must be infinite.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much! I sincerely appreciate it!