# Counterexamples for $L^{p}(\mathbb{R})$ spaces inclusion

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I know that there's a theorem that gives us inclusions if the space I am considering has a finite measure. However, if I consider the case $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, there shouldn't be any inclusion. I know that $L^2$ is not contained in $L^1$, I just have to take $1/x$ as an example. But what is a function that disproves the other inclusion? I can't find any.

Comment: Do you mean [this duplicate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18395/what-functions-or-classes-of-functions-are-l1-but-not-l2)?

Comment: Well, in the question it isn't specified where he is integrating. However I did find the anwer to my problem in the answers below. It was pretty simple, too...