# Measurable function, $f$, with $\int_{(0,1)} |f(x)| dm(x) < \infty$ and $\int_{(0,1)} (f(x))^{2} dm(x) = \infty$?

Tags: measure-theory, functions, lebesgue-measure

I need to think of an example of a measurable function that satisfies
\begin{equation}
\int_{(0,1)} |f(x)| dm(x) < \infty
\quad \text{and}
\int_{(0,1)} (f(x))^{2} dm(x) = \infty.
\end{equation}
I've been thinking about this for a while now and I can't seem to think of an example. It seems rather counterintuitive.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18395/what-functions-or-classes-of-functions-are-l1-but-not-l2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ is one example.