# Inequality between $\ell^p$-norms

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose that a sequence $x=(x_n)$ belongs both to $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ ($p,q>1$, $p\neq q$).
Is there any inequality between $\|x\|_p$ and $\|x\|_q$. Can one $\ell^p$ be continuously embedded into another $\ell^q$?

Comment: The map $p\mapsto ||x||_p$ is decreasing.

Comment: You do not need the restriction $p,q>1$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/how-do-you-show-that-l-p-subset-l-q-for-p-leq-q/4122#4122

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If $1 \leq p \leq q \lt \infty$ then $\|x\|_{q} \leq \|x\|_{p}$ and clearly $\|x\|_p \geq \|x\|_\infty$. In particular, $\ell^p$ embeds continuously into $\ell^q$ whenever $p \leq q$.

To see this, note that both sides of the inequality $\|x\|_{q} \leq \|x\|_{p}$ are homogeneous in $x$ (multiplying $x$ with a positive real number multiplies both sides with the same positive factor), so we may take without loss of generality an $x$ with $\|x\|_{p} = 1$. Then $\|x\|_{q}^{q} = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} |x_{j}|^{q} \leq \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} |x_{j}|^{p} = 1$, and this is because for $t \leq 1$ and $p \leq q$ we have $t^{q} \leq  t^{p}$.

This means that $p \mapsto \|x\|_p$ is decreasing. In terms of spaces, we have the inclusions $\ell^1 \subset \ell^p \subset \ell^q \subset \ell^{\infty}$ whenever $1 \lt p \lt q \lt \infty$ and it is not hard to show that the inclusions are all strict.

Note that this is opposite to the case of *finite* measure spaces $(\Omega,\mu)$, where the inclusions go the other way around: $L^1(\Omega,\mu) \supset L^p(\Omega,\mu) \supset L^{q}(\Omega,\mu) \supset L^{\infty}(\Omega,\mu)$.

See also [the Wikipedia page on $L^p$-spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: Where did you defined $ {x}_{j} \leq 1 $?

Comment: @Royi If a sum of non-negative terms is $1$ then every term is $0 \leq |x_j| \leq 1$.

Comment: Why does the summation go to infinity?