# How to prove the following inequality with different exponents?

Tags: inequality

$$
\left( \sum |z_i|^a \right)^b \geq \left( \sum |z_i|^b \right)^a, \quad \forall a\in [1,2], b\in [2,+\infty)
$$

**Note that $a$ and $b$ are not necessarily to be integer. $z_i$ is real.**

Thanks, guys.

Comment: A good answer for this question: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/36207/4076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you raise both sides to $\frac{1}{ab}$ you get:

$$\left(\sum \lvert z_i\rvert^a\right)^\frac{1}{a}\ge\left(\sum \lvert z_i\rvert^b\right)^\frac{1}{b}$$

which can be written as $\lVert z\rVert_a\ge\lVert z\rVert_b$

But this is a well-known result, see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69125/inequality-between-ellp-norms)