# How can I prove that this set is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

> Let $p\in [1,2)$ and define $B=\{(x_n)_n: \sum_n |x_n|^p\leq R\}$ for any $R>0$. I need to show that this set is closed in $\ell^2$.

My idea was the following.

Let me pick $(x^{(k)})_k=((x_n^{(k)})_n)_k\in B$ a convergent sequence, say $((x_n^{(k)})_n)_k\rightarrow (x_n)_n$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$. I need to show that $(x_n)_n\in B$. Hence consider $$\begin{align} \sum_n |x_n|^p&=\sum_n \left|\left(x_n-x_n^{(k)}\right)+x_n^{(k)}\right|^p\\&\leq\sum_n \left(\left|\left(x_n-x_n^{(k)}\right)\right|+\left|x_n^{(k)}\right|\right)^p \end{align}$$

Now the problem is that here I need to apply the Binomial Theorem to continue, hence I wanted to ask if there is an easier way to find an upper bound. I want to separate this two summands since I know that $\sum_n |x_n^{(k)}|^p\leq R$ and $\sum_n \left|\left(x_n-x_n^{(k)}\right)\right|^p $ can be bounded since $((x_n^{(k)})_n)_k\rightarrow (x_n)_n$.

Could maybe someone give me a hint how to proceed?

Comment: I think you can use convexity argument: $f(t)=t^p$ is convex for $t>0$, so $(\frac{a+b}{2})^p\le \frac{a^p+b^p}{2}$, $a,b\ge 0$.

Comment: @Vit I'm not convinced yet, because as I remember, your property is called midpoint convex and where should I get my $\frac{\cdot}{2}$?

Comment: Well, $|x_n|^p=2^p|\frac{x_n}{2}|^p$.

Comment: @Vit But let me pick $a=0.2$ and $b=1.5$ and $p=0.5$, then $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^p=0.92195$ but $\frac{a^p+b^p}{2}=0.57716$ so $t^p$ is not midpoint convex or am I wrong?

Comment: I assumed $p>1$.

Comment: I see thanks a lot

Comment: @Vit but at the end I get $2^{p-1}||x_n-x_n^{(k)}||_2^2+R2^{p-1}$. I know that the first summand converges to $0$ as $k\rightarrow \infty$ but then I still have $R2^{p-1}$ which is not less or equal then $R$

Comment: I misunderstood your "for any $R>0$". I thought you meant for all finite values $R$, not some fixed one. Anyway, I don't see how you can get the bound with this method then since you assume that it's possible to have $\sum_n x_n^{(k)}= R$ and $|(x_n-x_n^{(k)})|>0$.

Comment: $B$ is closed because its the continuous preimage of a closed set

Comment: The function $f(x)=\|x\|_p=\left (\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_,n|^p\right)^{1/p}$ satisfies $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le f(x-y)\le \|x-y\|_2.$$ Hence it is continuous. The set is if the form $\{x\in\ell^2\:\, f(x)\le R\}.$ Thus the set is closed.

Comment: Echoing @RyszardSzwarc, for $1 \le p \le q \le \infty$ we have $\|x\|_p \le \|x\|_q$ (on the $l_r$ spaces, that is). Hence if $x_n \to x$ in $l_2$ then $x_n \to x$ in $l_p$ since $p \in [1,2)$.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc for $p\le 2$, isn't the inequality in the other direction ? See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/69127/857384) for instance, we have $$\|x\|_q\le\|x\|_p $$ when $p\le q$

Comment: @StratosFair Right!! Thanks. My answer is correct for $p>2.$ The funny thing is that I have mislead copper hat

Comment: @copper.hat My comment is wrong. Sorry for the  misleading.

Comment: This follows directly from Fatou's Lemma.

Comment: Another reminder not to drink and derive!

Comment: @copper.hat  For me: not to watch ATP finals while answering questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer in my comment is wrong (thanks @StratosFair). Let $R>0.$ Assume $x^{(n)}\in B$ and $\|x^{(n)}-x\|_2\to 0.$ Thus $x^{(n)}_k\to x_k$ for any $k.$ Then
for any fixed $K$ we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^K|x_k|^p=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^K|x_k^{(n)}|^p\le R$$
Hence $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_k|^p\le R$$ Thus $x\in B.$