# Monotonicity of $\ell_p$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, optimization, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Consider a $n$ dimensional space, it is known (Wikipedia) that for $p>r>0$, we have

$$
\|x\|_p\leq\|x\|_r\leq n^{(1/r-1/p)}\|x\|_p.
$$

I have two questions about the above inequality.

$(\bf 1)$. The first is how to show $\|x\|_p\leq\|x\|_r$ when $p,r\leq1$. When $p>r\geq1$, we can define $$f(s)=\|x\|_s,\,\,s\geq1$$ and find out that $$f'(s)=\|x\|_s\left\{-\frac{1}{s^2}\log(\sum_i|x_i|^s)+\frac{1}{s}\frac{\sum_i|x_i|^s\log(|x_i|)}{\sum_i|x_i|^s}\right\}.$$

Then by the concavity of the $\log$ function, we can see that $$\frac{\sum_i|x_i|^s\log(|x_i|)}{\sum_i|x_i|^s}\leq \log\left(\sum_i\frac{|x_i|^s}{\sum_j|x_j|^s}\cdot|x_i|\right).$$
Let $$y_i=\frac{|x_i|^s}{\sum_j|x_j|^s},$$ it is easy to see $\|y\|_{s^*}\leq1$, where $s^*\geq1$ and $1/s+1/s^*=1$. Then, the Hölder's inequality leads to
$$\frac{\sum_i|x_i|^s\log(|x_i|)}{\sum_i|x_i|^s}\leq \log\left(\sum_i\frac{|x_i|^s}{\sum_j|x_j|^s}\cdot|x_i|\right)= \log\left(\sum_iy_i\cdot|x_i|\right)\leq\log(\|x\|_s\|y\|_{s^*})\leq\log\|x\|_s.$$
Therefore, we can conclude $f'(s)\leq0$ and $\|x\|_p\leq\|x\|_r$ is satisfied. However, when $p,r<1$, we do not have $s^*\geq1$ and $\|y\|_{s^*}\leq1$. The last step does not work any more.

(${\bf 2}$). My second question is how to show $\|x\|_r\leq n^{(1/r-1/p)}\|x\|_p.$ In fact, I was trying to show this by solving the following optimization problem:

$$
\max_{\|x\|_p\leq1} \|x\|_r.
$$
But seems it is difficult to derive a closed form solution. The objective function is non-smooth. Is there any elegant way to solve the above optimization problem?

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answers your first question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114650/ellp-subseteq-ellq-for-0pq-infty-and-cdot-p-cdot-q/114652#114652)

As for the second question. Consider Holder inequality
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |a_ib_i|\leq \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |a_i|^{s/(s-1)}\right)^{1-1/s}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |b_i|^s\right)^{1/s}
$$
with $a_i=1$, $b_i=|x_i|^r$, $s=p/r$.

Comment: I have a question, the link that you redirect the first question,  proves this inequality with sequences, wich means that the dimension of the space is infinite, however at the beginning of the question says "n dimensional space", isn't it different? I was thinking that if we want to use it with sequences first we do it for "finite sequences" (x_1,...,x_n) and then take limits

Comment: Yes, you can prove it this way

Answer (score 5):

For (i): Let $p>r>0$ and define $\|x\|_p = (\sum_{i} |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$.

First suppose that $\|x\|_p=1$. Then $\|x\|_p^p=1$ and $|x_i|\le 1$ for all $i$. Since $p>r$, we obtain $|x_i|^p \le |x_i|^r$ for all $i$ and, therefore,

$$1=\|x\|_p^p = \sum_{i} |x_i|^p \le \sum_{i} |x_i|^r = \|x\|_r^r.$$

Hence, $\|x\|_r \ge 1 = \|x\|_p$.

In the general case, set $y_i=x_i/\|x\|_p$, $y$ the vector with components $y_i$. Then $\|y\|_p=1$ and we can use the first part of the proof to obtain

$$
1=\|y\|_p \le \|y\|_r= \frac{\|x\|_r}{\|x\|_p}.
$$

This works for all $p>r>0$ when we define $\|x\|_p = (\sum_{i} |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$. However, for $p<1$, this does not define a norm since it is not sub-additive. See the lines after the formula you quote from Wikipedia. Sometimes the formula $\|x\|_p=\sum_{i} |x_i|^p$ is used in the case $p<1$.

Answer (score 0):

For (2), I shall state and prove the more general result :
Suppose $X$ is a finite measure space; and $1\leq p\leq q\leq\infty$. If $f\in L^q$, then $f\in L^p$, and $||f||_p\leq \mu (X)^{\frac1p -\frac1q}||f||_q$.

If $|f(x)|\geq1$, then $|f(x)|^p\leq|f(x)|^q$. If $|f(x)|\leq1$, then $|f(x)|^p\leq1$. So, $|f|^p\leq|f|^q+1$ which gives $\int|f|^p\leq\int|f|^q+\mu(x)<\infty$. Now $\frac qp\geq1$ and $f^p\in L^{\frac qp}$. By Holder's inequality, $||f^p.1||_1\leq||f^p||_{\frac qp}.||1||_s$ where $\frac pq+\frac 1s=1$. We get $\int |f|^p\leq(\int|f|^q)^{\frac pq}\mu(x)^\frac 1s$, or $||f||_p\leq\mu(x)^{\frac 1{ps}}||f||_q$.
Your question is answered when you realize that $(${$1,2,...,n$}$,\mathcal P(${$1,2,...,n$}$),\text{counting measure})$ is a finite measure space of measure $n$.

For (1), define $y_k=\frac{x_k}{||x||_q}$. $\forall k,|y_k|\leq1$. Thus, $|y_k|^q\leq|y_k|^p$. On summation we get, $||x||^p_q\leq \sum|x_k|^p \implies ||x||_q\leq||x||_p$.