# Monotonicity of $\ell_{p}$ norm and Holder's inequality

Tags: inequality

For any vector $x \in \mathbf{R}^{n}$, and any natural numbers $p \geq q \geq 1$, we have that $\lVert x \rVert_{p} \leq \lVert x \rVert_{q}$. Some proofs of this fact are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114650/ellp-subseteq-ellq-for-0pq-infty-and-cdot-p-cdot-q/114652#114652) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/how-do-you-show-that-l-p-subset-l-q-for-p-leq-q). However, I am interested in proving this result using Holder's inequality. This is left as an exercise for the reader in *An Introduction to Inequalities* by Beckenbach and Bellman. In that text, they prove the case when $p = 3$ and $q = 2$ as follows. First, we write
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{3}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}| |x_{i}|^{2}.
$$
We note that the right side of this equation is the inner product of $(|x_{1}| , \ldots , |x_{n}|)$ and $(|x_{1}|^{2} , \ldots , |x_{n}|^{2})$. Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to this inner product, we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{3}
\leq
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{4} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.
$$
To continue, we note that
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{2} \right)^{2}
-
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{4} \right)
=
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{\begin{subarray}{c} j=1 \\ j \neq i \end{subarray}}^{n} |x_{i}|^{2} |x_{j}|^{2} \geq 0 ,
$$
where the inequality follows from the fact that a sum of nonnegative quantities is nonnegative. Rearranging this inequality, and taking square roots, we have that
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{4} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{2}.
$$
Applying this result to one of our earlier inequalities, we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{3}
\leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{2} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}}.
$$
Taking the cube root of both sides yields the desired result. The text says that "the proof for arbitrary rational $m \geq n \geq 1$ can be obtained by a corresponding application of Holder's inequality." In analogy with the proof given above, using Holder's inequality instead of Cauchy's inequality, we have that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{p}
= \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}| |x_{i}|^{p-1}
\leq
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{q} \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{\frac{q (p-1)}{q-1}} \right)^{\frac{q-1}{q}}
\leq
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} |x_{i}|^{q} \right)^{\frac{p}{q}}.
$$
In order to justify this chain of inequalities, we still need to show that
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{\frac{q(p-1)}{q-1}} \right)^{\frac{q-1}{q}}
\leq
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}^{q} \right)^{\frac{p-1}{q}}.
$$
Letting $z_{i} = x_{i}^{\frac{q}{q-1}}$, this inequality is equivalent to
$$
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}^{p-1} \right)^{q-1}
\leq
\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} z_{i}^{q-1} \right)^{p-1}.
$$
But I am stuck at this point. (Recall that $p \geq q \geq 1$.) Any thoughts? Note that this comes from an elementary textbook, so ideally the answer should only use precalculus mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Hölder's inequality in the following way:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p = \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^{q-1} |x_i|^{p+1-q} \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left(|x_i|^{q-1}\right)^{\frac{q}{q-1}} \right)^{\frac{q-1}{q}} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \left(|x_i|^{p+1-q}\right)^{q} \right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \le \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^{q} \right)^{\frac{q-1}{q}} \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^{q} \right)^{\frac{p+1-q}{q}} = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^{q} \right)^{\frac{p}{q}}.$$

Comment: Nice. I would only add that the second inequality is equivalent to $\sum |z_{i}|^{k} \leq (\sum |z_{i}|)^{k}$, which is obvious because the difference between the right and left sides of the inequality is the sum of all the cross terms in $(\sum |z_{i}|)^{k}$, all of which are nonnegative.

Comment: I think the proof is incomplete. The second inequality is actually the special case that 1-norm is larger than any p-norm. The power is not integer, so you cannot use combinatorics to justify the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The last inequality you have to show is actually Hölder's inequality, but for the exponents $p':=p-1$ and $q':=q-1$. This suggests a proof by induction.