# Question about $\lim _{q \rightarrow \infty}\|f\|_{q}=\|f\|_{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Let $(X,B,\mu)$ be a complete measure space,Show that $$\lim _{q \rightarrow \infty}\|f\|_{q}=\|f\|_{\infty}, \quad \forall f \in \bigcup_{p} \bigcap_{p \leqslant q<\infty} L^{q}$$
So,$\lim _{q \rightarrow \infty}\|f\|_{q}$ , $\|f\|_{\infty}$ are equal-norm with space $ L^{\infty} \cap\left(\bigcup_{p} \bigcap_{p \leqslant q} L^{q}\right)$.

Case 1: $m(X)<\infty $.It's easy to prove that.

Case 2: $m(X)=\infty $. I have no idea about it,And I started to doubt the correctness of this conclusion.
Can somebody give me a hint for this problem or just give an example to prove that this is a wrong conclusion when $m(X)=\infty $.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need that $f\in L^\infty$ as well, so that the statement is actually true.

Comment: I'm not sure that you need cases for $m(X)$. One direction is simply the application that $||f||_q \leq ||f||_p^{p/q}||f||_\infty^{1-p/q}$

Comment: @K. Y Thanks for your answer first.Let $f \in \bigcup_{p}\bigcap_{p \leqslant q<\infty}L^{q}$,but not $L^{\infty}$,then exists $q_0 \in \mathbb{N}$,$\forall q>q_0,f \in L^q$.We define $E=\{x:|f(x)|>M\}$,Then $0<m(E)<\infty$(If $m(E)=\infty,\|f\|_{q} \geqslant\left(\int_{E}|f|^{q} d \mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \geqslant M|E|^{\frac{1}{q}}$,We get $f \notin L^q$).Observing inequality $\|f\|_{q} \geqslant\left(\int_{E}|f|^{q} d \mu\right)^{\frac{1}{q}} \geqslant M|E|^{\frac{1}{q}}$,Let $q \rightarrow \infty$,Actually we prove that $\varliminf_{q \rightarrow \infty}\|f\|_{q} \geqslant\|f\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: See [functions in $L^p$ but not $L^\infty$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/90672/598636)

Comment: @K. Y I think $\infty$ also can be the limit of some 
sequence,So...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following argument does not really on any finiteness assumptions on $\mu$. The only general assumptions is that $f\in L_r$ for some $r>0$.

If $\|f\|_\infty=0$ the conclusion is trivial. There are two cases other cases to consider: $0<\|f\|_\infty<\infty$ and $\|f\|_\infty=\infty$.

1. Assume first that $0<\|f\|_\infty<\infty$ and $f\in L_r$ for some $r>0$. Then $|f|/\|f\|_\infty<1$ a.s. For $p>r$
   $$\frac{|f|^p}{\|f\|^p_\infty}\leq \frac{|f|^r}{\|f\|^r_\infty}\in L_1$$
   hence $p\in E:=\{s: \|f\|_s<\infty\}$. Integrating on both side yields
   $$\frac{\|f\|_p}{\|f\|_\infty}\leq\Big(\frac{\|f\|_r}{\|f\|_\infty}\Big)^{r/p}\xrightarrow{p\rightarrow\infty}1$$
   That is,
   $$\limsup_p\|f\|_p\leq \|f\|_\infty.$$
   By the Markov-Chebyshev inequality, for any $0<\alpha<\|f\|_\infty$
   $$0<\alpha\big(\mu(|f|>\alpha)\big)^{1/p}\leq\|f\|_p$$
   Hence $\alpha\leq\liminf_p\|f\|_p$ and so,
   $\|f\|_\infty\leq\liminf_p\|f\|_p$. The conclusion follows.
2. Now assume that $\|f\|_p=\infty$ and $f\in L_r$ for some $r>0$. Then $0<\mu(|f|>n)\leq\frac{1}{n^r}\|f\|^r_r<\infty$ and so,
   $$0<n\big(\mu(|f|>n)\big)^{1/p}\leq\|f\|_p\quad\text{for}\quad p\geq r$$
   This implies $n\leq\liminf_p\|f\|_p$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The conclusion follows.

---

The assumption  $f\in L_r$ for some $r>0$ may not dropped in general. Consider the measure space $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}),m)$ where $m$ Lebesgue's measure.  The function $f(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,\infty)}(x)$ is measurable, and  $\|f\|_p=\infty$ for all $p>0$, while  $\|f\|_\infty=1$.

Comment: Excellent Answer!

Comment: Notice that is enough to have $f\in\bigcup_{p>0}L_p$ for the statement to hold.

Comment: You are right.Thanks.

Comment: Actually,Because $f\in L_r$ for some $r>0$,Then $\mu(|f|>n)<K(n)<\infty$.

Comment: @Johnstein: Here is a related problem that may be of interest which can be solve with methods similar to what we did here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1482933/an-inequality-about-lp-norm/3740659#3740659