# Brezis's Exercise 4.6: is the assumption $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ necessary?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I'm trying to solve below exercise in Brezis's *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. Assume $f \in \bigcap_{p \in [1, \infty)} L^p (\Omega)$ and there is $C \in [0, \infty)$ such that $\|f\|_p \le C$ then $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$.

- Could you confirm if my below attempt is correct?
- Could you confirm if the assumption $\mu(\Omega) < \infty$ is not needed?

---

**Proof** Fix $K> C$. We have
$$
\mu (\{|f| \ge K\}) =\int 1_{\{|f|^p \ge K^p\}} \mathrm d \mu \le \int \frac{|f|^p}{K^p} 1_{\{|f|^p \ge K^p\}} \mathrm d \mu \le \bigg ( \frac{\|f\|_p}{K} \bigg)^p \le \bigg ( \frac{C}{K} \bigg)^p.
$$

Taking the limit $p \to \infty$, we get
$$
\mu (\{|f| \ge K\}) =0.
$$

Hence $\|f\|_\infty \le K$ and thus $\|f\|_\infty \le C$. This completes the proof.

Comment: So you assume that the bound $\lVert f\rVert_p\leq C$ is uniform in $p\geq1$? In that case I see no problems with your solution.

Comment: @jakobdt oh yess, the bound is uniform in $p$. Thank you so much for your verification!

Comment: Finiteness is not require. It all follows from the [fact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3739548/121671) that $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\|f\|_p=\|f\|_\infty$. The assumption in your posting means that $\|f\|_\infty\leq C$.