# Using Holder's inequality to prove p-norms

Tags: real-analysis

If $f \in$ C$([0,1])$ and $1\le r \le s \le \infty$, $ \ $ 
show that $\lVert f \rVert_1 \le \lVert f \rVert_r \le \lVert f \rVert_s \le \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}. \ $

Hint: Use Holder's inequality with $g(x)=1$ and exponent $p = \frac{s}{r}$. Hence, show that if $ (f_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \in$ C$([0,1])$ converges uniformly to $ f \in$ C$([0,1])$, then the sequence also converges with respect to the norm $\lVert \ . \rVert_p$ for any $1 \le p \lt \infty$

Holder's Inequality: $\lVert fg \rVert_1 \le \lVert f \rVert_p \lVert g \rVert_q$; $\ $ where $ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$

My thoughts/attempt:

Let $g(x)=1$ and apply Holder's inequality with $p = \frac{s}{r}.  \ $ Now, $ \ \lVert fg \rVert_1 = \lVert f \rVert_1 \le \lVert f \rVert_{\frac{s}{r}}$

I get to this point and I just cannot see how Holder's Inequality and then the sequences are supposed to help me here.

I know that p norms get progressively bigger until the infinity norm.

I also see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483686/monotonicity-of-ell-p-norm-and-holders-inequality) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775483/application-of-h%C3%B6lders-inequality-on-mathbb-rn?noredirect=1&lq=1) how this sort of thing is done when we're just talking about a vector $\textbf{x}$. Because we just invoke the definition of a p-norm and go from there. Although, even then, the part where $\lVert f \rVert_s \le \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}$ is not immediately clear to me.

Something is confusing me. I think one of the issues might be that we're talking about $f$ here and not a vector $\textbf{x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*One confusing fact to keep in mind: for vectors ($\ell_p$ spaces), the $p$-norms are non-increasing. For functions ($L_p$ spaces), they are non-decreasing.*

---

Let $1\leq r\leq s\leq \infty$. Applying Hölder's inequality to $f^r g$ *(that's the trick)* you have, since $g=1$,
$$
\lVert f^r \rVert_1
= \lVert f^rg \rVert_1
\operatorname*{\leq}_{\rm Hölder}
= \lVert f^r \rVert_p \lVert g \rVert_q 
= \lVert f^r \rVert_p
$$
where $p\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\frac{s}{r} \geq 1$ and $q\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p}} \geq 1$. But
$$
\lVert f^r \rVert_p = \left(\int {f^{rp}}\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}
= \left(\int {f^{s}}\right)^{\frac{r}{s}}
$$
so, raising both sides to the power $\frac{1}{r}$, we get
$$
\lVert f \rVert_r=\lVert f^r \rVert_1^{\frac{1}{r}} \leq \left(\int {f^{s}}\right)^{\frac{1}{s}}=\lVert f \rVert_s
$$
which is what we wanted.

Comment: That "confusing part" really is confusing. I was definitely having some mix-ups in my brain in that regard. In regards to the solution: so, the entire trick is really to just raise f to the power r? That seems simple enough. A couple of thoughts: 1) what is the point of the whole sequence converging uniformly... part? That seems useless. 2) Can I take for granted $\lVert f \rVert_1 \le \lVert f \rVert_r$ and $\lVert f \rVert_s \le \lVert f \rVert_{\infty}$ or do I need to show those separately?

Comment: The sequence part, I cannot make sense of it -- it's probably another part of the exercise whose statement is missing (and the part about the $p$-norms helps to show it), since there is no sequence $(f_n)_n$ in what you wrote.

Comment: @DudeWah Regarding the rest, well: it works for every $1\leq r\leq s\leq \infty$, so to prove those, just take $r=1$ to show $\lVert f\rVert_1\leq \lVert f\rVert_s$; take $s=\infty$ to show to show $\lVert f\rVert_r\leq \lVert f\rVert_\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I will think about this some more and formalize my thoughts.

Comment: You're welcome!