# An $\ell_1$ $\ell_2$ inequality in Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space, $x \in X$, $\{e_i\}$ a countably infinite orthonormal basis.

I think I remember seeing in a book that 
$$
\sum_{i} |\langle x,e_i \rangle| \leq 4 \left( \sum_{i} |\langle x,e_i \rangle |^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$
(or something like that). But I can't find this inequality anywhere and can't seem to prove it.

How can it be proved or disproved?

By Parseval, the right-hand side is $4\| x \|_2$.

I know the inequality 
$$
 \sum_{i} |c_i|  \leq C \left( \sum_{i} |c_i|^2 \right)^{1/2}
$$
cannot hold in general (See the answer to [$\ell^p\subseteq\ell^q$ for $0<p<q<\infty$ and $\|\cdot\|_p<\|\cdot\|_q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114650/ellp-subseteq-ellq-for-0pq-infty-and-cdot-p-cdot-q?noredirect=1&lq=1) )

But maybe there is some orthogonality or parallelogram law trick that works when $c_i = \langle x,e_i \rangle$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be no such inequality. To see this, let $N$ be a positive integer and let
$$
x = \sum_{j=1}^N \frac{1}{j} e_j.
$$
Then
$$
\ln(N+1) < \sum_{j=1}^N |\langle x, e_j \rangle|
$$
but
$$
\sum_{j=1}^N |\langle x, e_j \rangle|^2 < \frac{\pi^2}{6}.
$$
Thus the left side of the alleged inequality gets arbitrarily large as $N$ gets large, but the right side stays bounded.