# $d(f,g)=\int_X |f-g|^p d\mu$ defines metric space when $0<p\leq 1$

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, lp-spaces

I have tried solving this problem.

> Show that  $$d(f,g)=\int_X |f-g|^p d\mu$$ defines metric space when $0<p\leq 1$.

The only thing I need to show is triangular inequality.

I have tried to use Holder inequality but it does not work since $p\leq 1$. So I think, I need to prove that

$$|f-h|^p\leq |f-g|^p+|g-h|^p$$

directly. Buy I don't know how... seems very easy... but ....

Any hint or answer would be helpful! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the triangle inequality, you can expand as:

$$
|f-h|^p = |f-g+g-h|^p \leq (|f-g|+|g-h|)^p
$$

And then you can use the result given by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264156/prove-that-pqm-leq-pmqm) to get your result.

Comment: It turned out that the link in this answer was not appropriate to answer my question. Here is a correct link that I found .   https://math.stackexchange.com/q/134714/523306

Comment: It wasn't? Could you explain why so I could edit my answer?

Comment: The function value of $f$ and $g$ can be negative. Your link only deals with positive number. Note that he used the property that $(p+q)^{t-1}\leq p^{t-1}$ which is not true if we switch $(p+q)$ to $|p+q|$ with positive $p$ and negative $q$.

Comment: Right, and this is why, in my answer, I mentioned that we should first use the triangle inequality.

Comment: I was trying to understand based on your argument but I could not, Could you expand your answer a little bit?

Comment: I suppose, but I'm not sure it'll be helpful. The regular triangle inequality gives us $|f-g+g-h| \leq |f-g| + |g-h|$, and so we know that $|f-g+g-h|^p \leq (|f-g| + |g-h|)^p$. Then if we let $a=|f-g|$ and $b=|g-h|$, both $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative, so we can use the link I provided to get $(a+b)^p \leq a^p + b^p$. Combining this with the above inequality, we get the desired $|f-g+g-h|^p \leq |f-g|^p + |g-h|^p$.

Comment: You are right!   I think I made a mistake..  Thanks!