# Show $(|a|+|b|)^p \leq |a|^p+|b|^p$ for $0\leq p \leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

How to show that for any real numbers $a$ and $b$ 
$$(|a|+|b|)^p \leq |a|^p+|b|^p$$
for $0\leq p \leq 1$ ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264156/prove-that-pqm-leq-pmqm

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is equivalent to
$$ x^p+y^p\ge 1, \text{ for }x+y=1,x,y\ge0.$$
Noting that, for $p\in[0,1],x,y\in[0,1]$,
$$ x^p\ge x,y^p\ge y $$
one has
$$ x^p+y^p\ge 1. $$

Answer (score 1):

You want
$(a+b)^p
\le a^p+b^p
$
with
$a \ge 0, b \ge 0, 0 \le p \le 1$.

We can assume that
$a \le b
$.

If $a=0$
this is
$b^p \le b^p$,
which is true.
So we can assume that
$a > 0$.

If $a=b$,
this becomes
$2^pa^p \le 2a^p
$
or
$2^p \le 2$
which is true.
So we can assume
$0 < a < b$.

Dividing by $b^p$,
this is
$(r+1)^p
\le r^p+1
$
where
$r = \frac{a}{b}
$
and
$0 < r < 1$.

If $p=1$ this is
$r+1 \le r+1$
which is true,
so we can assume that
$0 \le p < 1$.

Let
$f(r)
= r^p + 1 - (r+1)^p
$.

$f(0)
=0
$,
$f(1)
=2-2^p
\ge 0$,
and

$\begin{array}\\
f'(r)
&=pr^{p-1}-p(r+1)^{p-1}\\
&=pr^{p-1}(1-(1+1/r)^{p-1})\\
&\ge 0\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$1+1/r > 1$
and
$-1 \le p-1 < 0$,
$(1+1/r)^{p-1}
\lt 1$,
so $f'(r) \ge 0$
so $f(r) \ge 0$
which is what we want.

This is probably too long,
but this is what I did.

Comment: "This is probably too long" dunno about that, but regardless it has the virtue of being straightforward in a way - ok, figure out how big it is and you're done. If I'd tried to do this there woulda been an argument like what happens with $f(r)$ above...