# Prove or disprove the given inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $a, b\geq 0$, then prove or disprove $$(a+b)^{r}\leq a^r+b^r$$ where $r \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What's your own work on the subject? There are two values of $r$ for which the inequality becomes very easy...

Comment: This is identical to [Prove that $(p+q)^m \leq p^m+q^m$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/264156/9464)