# Is there a meaning of distances for 0<p<1 for Wasserstein distance?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, wasserstein

The wikipedia link for Wasserstein metric is defined for $p\in[1,\infty)$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric  Given some data the distance can be calculated using an optimization routine. In the routine one can choose any value for $0<p<1$ and obtain a solution. The question is can we interpet the solution as a valid distance, with proper meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $0<p<1$, $d_p(x,y)\equiv (d(x,y))^{p}$ is a metric on your original space. Thus, you can define a Wasserstein $p$ metric for $(d(x,y))^{p}$ as the Wasserstein $1$ metric for $d_p(x,y)$ in the usual setting.

Comment: Do you mean Wasserstein metric 1 is valid for p<1? Further even for p<1 it is called as Wasserstein metric 1?

Comment: I would say it is the most natural way to define the Wasserstein $p$ metric for $p<1$. I have not seen anywhere where Wasserstein $p$ metric is explicitly defined for $p<1$ (In the *computational optimal transport* by Peyré and Cuturi, it is just mentioned in remark 2.15). In a lot of cases, the convexity of the cost function is needed to produce many results in optimal transport but $|x-y|^{p}$ is non-convex for $p<1$. I don't know anything other than that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reference.

Comment: Would you mind to explain why $(d(x,y))^p)$ is a metric in the original space only when $p<1$. I am not sure and still thinking of it.

Comment: It basically follows from the fact that $d(x,y)$ is a metric and $x \mapsto x^p$ is a strictly increasing function for nonnegative $x$. For triangular inequality, note the following [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264156/prove-that-pqm-leq-pmqm)

Comment: However, the inequality result doesn't hold when $p>1$ so it is a metric ONLY when $p\leqslant1$