# Inclusion of $l^p$ space for sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Inclusion of $L^p$ spaces for functions has been discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion). 
Does this apply to $l^p$ space of sequences similarly?

I tried to show the following: For $1\leq p<q<\infty$, $l^q\subset l^p$ By using Hölder inequality but it doesn't seem to work.

My question is that is this true? If yes, what's the right way to prove it and what's a good counter example for showing $l^p\subset l^q$ is not true? Thanks.

Comment: If a sequence $\{x_n\}_n$ is in $\ell^p$, then $x_n \to 0$. This implies a natural embedding of $\ell^p$ into $\ell^q$.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/how-do-you-show-that-l-p-subset-l-q-for-p-leq-q).

Comment: Thanks. so should I delete my question?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If $\sum_n |x_n|^p < \infty$, then $|x_n| \leq 1$ definitely. Therefore, if $q>p$, then $|x_n|^q \leq |x_n|^p$, and we conclude that $\ell^p \subset \ell^q$.

Now the opposite embedding can't be true, otherwise $\ell^p \simeq \ell^q$ for every pair $(p,q)$, and this is obviously false.

Comment: $|x_n|^q \leq |x_n|^p$ is true. but how do we control their powers since we have $(\sum_n |x_n|^p)^{1/p}$?

Comment: Also, how is $|x_n| \leq 1$ if we have a sequence with $2$ in the first term and infinite $0$s?

Comment: Come on, you can do better that this! I wrote *definitely*, i.e. beyond some large index. You should not care of the first terms, since they can be always bounded by some fixed constant.
Moreover, $|x_n|^q \leq |x_n|^p$ implies that $\|x_n\|_q^q \leq \|x_n\|_p^p$ by summation. Hence the injection $\imath \colon \ell^p \to \ell^q$ is continuous.

Comment: "can't be true because it's obviously false" does not make a good argument. You also commit a logical fallacy saying "for _every_ pair". Maybe it's true for _some_ pairs, not for all of them.

Comment: " I wrote definitely, i.e. beyond some large index": I think you meant *eventually*, not "definitely". And "$\ell^p \simeq \ell^q$" should be $\ell^p=\ell^q$.

Comment: why does the inclusion follow from $|x_{n}|^{q}≤|x_{n}|^{p} $?

Comment: @AnneBauval Of course, typical false friend for italians (we say "definitivamente" to mean "eventually").

Comment: @Siminore How funny, for us french, "éventuellement" means "possibly", and "définitivement" means "fixed for ever".

Answer (score 13):

For completeness, a counterexample for $p>q$: pick $s\in (1/p,1/q)$ and consider the sequence $x_n=1/n^s$. This sequence is in $\ell^p$ but not in $\ell^q$.