# For 1≤p<q≤$\infty$, show that $L^{p}(\mathbb{Z},\mu) \subset L^{q}(\mathbb{Z},\mu)$, $\mu$ being the counting measure.

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, holder-inequality

I have to show the inclusion $L^{p}(\mathbb{Z},\mu) \subset L^{q}(\mathbb{Z},\mu)$ with the counting measure. Using 1≤p<q≤$\infty$ and the definition of the $L^{p}/L^{q}$ spaces I have tried to mess around with Hölder's inequality and the integral in the given space (which is just summation) to somehow show the inclusion for a given function but have been unsuccesful until now.

Comment: $|x|^{q} \leq |x|^{p}$ if $|x| \leq 1$. That is all there is to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inclusion of $l^p$ space for sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669360/inclusion-of-lp-space-for-sequences) See not the question but the accepted answer.

Comment: It does indeed answer my question, but I'm not sure I understand how we got there. First, why does $|x|^{q}≤|x|^{p}$ follow from $|x|≤1$, second, why does $L^{p}(\mathbb{Z},\mu) \subset L^{q}(\mathbb{Z},\mu)$ follow from $|x|^{q}≤|x|^{p}$ ?