# Pairs $(p,q)$ such that $id: l_p\to l_q$ is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

> find all pairs $p,q\in [1,\infty)$ such that $id: l_p\to l_q$ is bounded.

This just means I must find all $(p,q)$ such that $\|x\|_q \le C\|x\|_p$ for some $C$ dependent on $p$, $q$. I don't know where to start, it seems like I'm missing something obvious

Comment: Start by finding out when you have $l_p \subset l_q$. That is a necessary condition. Is it also sufficient?

Comment: @DanielFischer We have $l_p\subset l_q$ iff p<q. It is also sufficient, take for example $y_k=\dfrac{1}{k^(1/p)}$. It is in $l_q$ but not in $l_p$. Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/how-do-you-show-that-l-p-subset-l-q-for-p-leq-q) and the posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4094). For a more general version, see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/66029).