# Is it true that $p<q \Longrightarrow \ell^p \subset \ell^q$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $1 \leq p \leq \infty$ and $1 \leq q \leq \infty$ be two intgers

Is it true that $p<q \Longrightarrow \ell^p \subset \ell^q$

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean $\ell^q\subset\ell^p$

Comment: yes, now i edited

Comment: The answer is: yes, it is true.

Comment: thanks @JasonBorn

Comment: duplicate of (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To see this note that if $\sum |a_n|^p < \infty$ then it must be that $|a_n|^p< 1$ for sufficiently large $n$. Hence since $\frac{q}{p} >1$ it follows that $|a_n|^q<|a_n|^p$, which implies the result

Comment: thanks @Christopher Halverson for your answer