# Show the following equation: $x^p+y^p\leqslant (x^2+y^2)^{p/2}$

Tags: inequality

> Assume that $p \geq 2$. Show the following equation: $x^p+y^p\leqslant (x^2+y^2)^{p/2}$

What is the right solution of this problem?
For $p=2$ it's easy.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Check your source. Do you want $p \geq 2$? E.g. $p=1, x = 3, y = 4$ is false.

Comment: Yes, I assume that $p \geq 2$

Comment: Then do not assume it in comments but rather include it in the main post, together with some more context (for example what have you tried).

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094/631742

Answer (score 1):

We shall prove that $\frac{d}{dp}(x^p+y^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq 0$, and this will prove the result.

Note that $\frac{d}{dp}(x^p+y^p)^{\frac{1}{p}} = \frac{(x^p+y^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}}{p^2(x^p+y^p)}(x^p \ln(x^p)+y^p \ln y^p - (x^p+y^p)\ln (x^p+y^p))$.

To prove it is negative, note that the expression inside the brackets is $f(x^p+y^p)-f(x^p)-f(y^p)$ where $f(z) = z \ln z$.

$f$ is convex everywhere so we establish the result.