# Does convergence in $l^q(\mathbb{R})$ of elements of $l^p(\mathbb{R})$ imply convergence in $l^p(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces

Let $1\le p<q\le \infty$ and $l^p(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of sequences of real numbers such that the series of absolute values of its terms to the power $p$ converges and $|\cdot|_p$ be the $p$-norm (the same for $l^q(\mathbb{R})$ and $|\cdot|_q$). I would like to know whether it is false or true that if a sequence of elements of $l^p(\mathbb{R})$ converges to an element in $l^p(\mathbb{R})$ using the $q$-norm  then the convergence also holds using the $p$-norm (this makes sense because $l^p(\mathbb{R})$ is a subspace of $l^p(\mathbb{R})$).

I did not manage to prove it and the usual counterexamples that look like an harmonic series do not seem to work. I would appreciate some help on how to approach this problem (not a whole solution, please).

Comment: Slightly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4094/631742

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider $\mathbf x_n:=(\underbrace{n^{-\frac1p},\ldots,n^{-\frac1p}}_{n\text{ times}},0,0,\ldots)$.