# Reverse of Young inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

By the discrete Young inequality, we know that $\|a_n * b_n\|_q \leq \|a_n\|_p \|b_n\|_r$ when $1/q+1= 1/p+1/r$.

My question is that if there exists $C>0$, such that $\|a_n * b_n\|_q \leq C \|a_n\|_p $ is true for any $a_n \in \ell^p$, can we have $q\geq p$ and $b_n\in \ell ^r$?

Any idea will be helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Young's inequality is truly beautiful. However, I have a problem understanding your question. 

1) I guess we fix $p\geq1$.  

2) Do you want this? **If  there is $C>0$ such that**
$$\|(a_n)*(b_n)\|_{\ell^r}\leq C\|(a_n)\|_{\ell^p}$$
for all $(a_n)\in\ell^p$ and all $(b_n)\in\ell^q$ with  $\|(b_n)\|_{\ell^q}\leq1$ then $$\dfrac{1}{r}+1=\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{q}$$

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment. This is exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This is false.

Take $(a_n)\in\ell^{p}$ and $(b_n)\in\ell^{q}$ where $p,q\geq 1$, then by Youngs inequality
$$\|(a_n)*(b_n)\|_{\ell^r}\leq \|(a_n)\|_{\ell^p}\|(b_n)\|_{\ell^q}$$
provided $$\dfrac{1}{r}+1=\dfrac{1}{p}+\dfrac{1}{q}$$
and then
$$\|(a_n)*(b_n)\|_{\ell^s}\leq\|(a_n)\|_{\ell^p}\|(b_n)\|_{\ell^q}$$
whenever $s>r$ (see [How do you show monotonicity of the $\ell^p$ norms?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/how-do-you-show-monotonicity-of-the-ellp-norms/4122#4122)), even though
$$\frac1s +1< \frac1p+\frac1q$$

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstood your comment before. My question is that if the convolution is true for any $a_n\in \ell^p$, what is the optimal $q$ such that $b_n \in \ell^q$.