# How do we show that $||x||_r \le ||x||_s$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Consider the normed spaced $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then how do I show that $||x||_r \le ||x||_s\ $ if   $\ 1\le s \le r \le \infty$?

So far I was trying to use Holder's inequality but made no progress at all. So I have nothing to show here.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Pehaps this may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/how-do-you-show-monotonicity-of-the-ellp-norms

Comment: You can get proper double norm bars by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Comment: This is very elementary. No need for Holder. Assume that RHS $\leq 1$ and show that LHS $\leq 1$. Then finish the proof.